# redirection from payment gateway to website make empty cart

Tags: magento2, cart, payment-gateway, order-status, redirect-url

We are using Paytm extension in our client's website https://www.safaribags.com which builds on Magento 2.1

When customers click on "Pay with Paytm" button, the customer redirects to the Paytm Pay URL. On the Paytm Pay URL, browser's back button is enabled, so when they click on that button, they redirect to the website but their cart would be empty every time.

So I want to know some solution for this issue.

This issue is in the live website, so please support ASAP.

Comment: Does your payment gatway provide cancel options there? Have you do code for that one?

Comment: Yes, the Cancel Payment button is there and when we click that button it will redirect to the website from the payment gateway page with restore all cart products. but this is not happening when we click the browser back button. I want to restore that cart item again if someone clicks browser back button @DhirenVasoya

Comment: I'm facing the same problems with my site [Genie Bags](https://www.geniebags.in/) . Please post a reply if you find some solution to this case.